# Can't access CSS variables in script tag of Vue file

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3, css-modules

### Problem

I am trying to access variables defined within an SCSS file from a `.vue` file. The project is using vue-cli.

According to [Vue's docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html):

> *"Vue CLI projects comes with support for PostCSS, CSS Modules and pre-processors including Sass, Less and Stylus."*

However, if I create a `variables.css` file with a variable called `variable`, and try to import it within the script, this `variable` is not found.

**styles/variables.module.css**

```
$variable: 'foo';

:export {
  variable: $variable
}
```

**App.vue**

```js
<script>
import variables from "./styles/variables.module.scss";
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    variable() {
      console.log(variables);  // Object {}
      return variables.variable || "not found";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Importing the variables.css file within the `<style module>` tag of the same vue file does work however.

**App.vue**

```js
<style module lang="scss">
@import "./styles/variables.module.scss";

:export {
  variable: $variable;
}
</style>
```

### What I'm trying to achieve

```html
<p>Importing within &lt;script&gt;, the variable is {{variable}}</p>
// 'not found', should be "foo"
<p>Importing within &lt;style&gt;, the variable is {{$style.variable}}</p>
// correctly showing "foo"
```

### Have tried:

- Adding `.module` to the SCSS file name (as per [vue's docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules))
- Creating a vue.config.js file with `requireModuleExtension: false`
  (from same docs)

### Reproducible demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-css-to-js-o9p2b?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: You're conflating CSS variables (`property: var(--some-name)`) with SCSS variables. They are different type of variables used for different purposes (CSS variables work in real time and can be parsed by CSSOM parser (browser), while SCSS variables are used by pre-processors to create CSS from SCSS) and can be parsed by SCSS/SASS parsers. On the bright side, as pointed out by @tuhin's answer, SCSS variables can be imported into `.(ts|js)` files while CSS variables not so much (although I might not be up to date with latest news on this front).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `webpack` and CSS [modular](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage) code into `webpack.config.js`.

```
npm install -D vue-loader vue-template-compiler webpack
```

Here is the working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-edison-70k9k?file=/src/App.vue)

**Note**: your `vue-template-compiler` and `vue` should be the same version

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I noticed your sandbox is in the container environment. Is this a necessity to get this working or just your personal preference?